# How to migrate the GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration to Reactive Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I have overridden `SecurityExpressionRoot` in my project exposing a method verifying whether the current user has rights to a given resource.

Then I have overriden GlobalMethodSecurityComfiguration.createExpressionHandler() and then createSecurityExpressionRoot() returning the instance of the overriden SecurityExpressionRoot.
This has worked in a servlet scenario, unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in a reactive scenario.

How do I convert the method security setup below to the reactive scenario?

In my tests I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

            at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]

            Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:

Error has been observed at the following site(s):

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers$MutatorFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

            |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/things/1/jobs/1/log" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
private final ThingsRepository thingsRepository;

```
@Override
protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    return new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
            DeployPermissionSecurityExpressionRoot root = new ThingsPermissionSecurityExpressionRoot(thingsRepository, authentication);
            root.setThis(invocation.getThis());
            root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
            root.setTrustResolver(getTrustResolver());
            root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
            return root;
        }
    };
}
```

My security config:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt(jwt ->{
                 jwt.jwtDecoder(jwtDecoder());
                 jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(customJwtAuthConverter());
            })
        .and()
        .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance());
    // @formatter:on
    return http.build();
}
```

SecurityExpressionRoot implementation:

```
class ThingsPermissionSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    private final ThingsRepository ThingsRepository;
    private Object filterObject;
    private Object returnObject;
    private Object target;

    ThingsPermissionSecurityExpressionRoot(ThingsRepository thingsRepository, Authentication authentication) {
        super(authentication);
        this.thingsRepository = thingsRepository;
    }

    public boolean hasThingsWritePrivilege(Long thingsId) {
```

Controller:

```
public class ThingsController {

    private final JobPublisherProvider jobPublisherProvider;

    @GetMapping("{thingsId}/jobs/{jobId}/log")
    @PreAuthorize("hasThingsWritePrivilege(#thingsId)")
    public Flux<DataBuffer> retrieveJobLog(@PathVariable String thingsId, @PathVariable int jobId) {
```

Controller test method

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(roles = {"ROLE_JAR_W"})
public void logValueProperlyRetrieved() {
```

Comment: Have you tried it with "@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity" on your config class, in place of  "@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity" ?

Comment: Yeah, the problem was with the dependencies, though.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to define GlobalSecurityConfiguration in a reactive Spring application (current Spring Security version 5.5.2).

In order to have the same functionality, you need to replace *methodSecurityExpressionHandler* defined in *ReactiveMethodSecurityConfiguration* with your own method security expression handler.

To do that, you can extend *DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler* and define it as @Primary bean.
For your case, it is going to be as following.

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
    DeployPermissionSecurityExpressionRoot root = new ThingsPermissionSecurityExpressionRoot(thingsRepository, authentication);
    root.setThis(invocation.getThis());
    root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
    root.setTrustResolver(getTrustResolver());
    root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
    root.setDefaultRolePrefix(getDefaultRolePrefix());
    return root;
  }
}
```

```
@Bean
@Primary
public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
  return new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5046#issuecomment-427097710